# background image not filling window

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a pop-up with a background image from CSS as below

```
#gui-01-Qa {
background-image:url(path/to//file.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: top left;
```

}

This all works fine apart from (what looks like) a boarder of approx 5px being added. It's not coming from my code, but both IE and Firefox are adding it. So whet's it coming from ????

Any ideas would help
Many thanks
Giles

Comment: Can you demonstrate some of your HTML code?

Comment: The rest of the html would help.
And as a blind guess, i would say there is a padding/margin somewhere in the parent or maybe inherited from some other css class. Best thing to do is, inspect the element with firebug and have a look at the real styles used.

Answer (score 0):

That border is most likely a padding or margin on the `body` element. Just add `html, body { margin:0; padding:0;}`, or use a [CSS reset](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=css+reset).

If you're wondering how to stretch a background image to fill the entire window regardless of resolution while preserving the aspect-ratio A List Apart recently published a [very good article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/supersize-that-background-please/) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the element with your CSS ID "gui-01-Qa" is causing the border. Try to set margin and/or padding to 0.